# How to use DataContract / DataMember annotations for particular service not for all services

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to use `[DataMember]` and `[DataContract]` annotations for Service A, but not for Service B.

Use these annotations only in the class `Emp` shown here:

```
[DataContract]
public class  Emp
{
    [DataMember]
    public int intId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string strName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes - nice - and what is the **question** you're asking?? You're showing us a class, some members with and other without the `[DataMember]` annotation - OK, but what is the **question**?!?!?

Comment: There is no way to conditionally *disable* attributes, depending on where the class is used. You either have your attributes always or you have two different classes, one with attributes and the other without.

Comment: As far as I know, it is impossible. I could not understand “for particular service not for all services”. I think we could fully achieve this requirement by defining two different classes.